# Reading from multiple topics in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to read from multiple kafka topics (say 'newtest-1' and 'newtest-2') using 'white_list' configuration in the logstash input plugin. My logstash conf looks like:

```
input { kafka { white_list => "newtest-1|newtest-2" } } output { stdout {codec => rubydebug } }
```

With this configuration I can successfully read from two different topics. But I want to use regex for input topics as I'm expecting the topics to be of the form 'newtest-*'. According to the suggestion in  [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-kafka-for-multiple-topics/27422) link, the following configuration should work:

```
input { kafka { white_list => "newtest-*" } } output { stdout {codec => rubydebug } }
```

But with this I'm not able to read from kafka. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `white_list` should be `newtest-.*`
This is relevant to older versions of the plugin. Now you can use `topics`.